# Alexa Skill Kit 24 Kilobyte Response Limit Change

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In the [Amazon Alexa developer docs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#response-format) it states that there is a 24 kilobyte limit on the size of the response JSON payload. I previously observed this limit being enforced but recently it seems the limit has been removed.

Does anyone know if this limit officially been removed and if so is there a new higher limit to the response size?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quoting straight from the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference):

> Note the following size limitations for the response:
>
> - The outputSpeech response cannot exceed 8000 characters.
> - All of the text included in a card cannot exceed 8000 characters. This includes the title, content, text, and image URLs.
> - An image URL (smallImageUrl or largeImageUrl) cannot exceed 2000 characters.
> - The token included in an audioItem.stream for the AudioPlayer.Play directive cannot exceed 1024 characters.
> - The url included in an audioItem.stream for the AudioPlayer.Play directive cannot exceed 8000 characters.
> - The total size of your response cannot exceed 24 kilobytes.
>
> If your response exceeds these limits, the Alexa service returns an error.

So, the limit you are asking is still valid.